# iPhone 6 iOS 9 how to fix blank screen - no apps visible

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I'm running into a weird issue over the last couple days where I can't see any content on the iOS "App Store" when viewed on the device. Blank screen is visible. It seems that I can still update apps, and the updates screen has updates available.

**How can I fix the "blank screen" problem with the Apple iOS App store?**

THere's no spinner visible and the app can just sit there with no content refreshing.

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you try force-quitting it? Double-click the Home button & swipe it up off the screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin that was the first thing I did. Haven't tried resetting th phone yet

Answer (score 5):

Tap on any one of the toolbar buttons (Featured, Search, Updates, etc.) on the bottom of the screen rapidly 10 times. It sounds counter-intuitive, but it will refresh the App Store and should solve your problem.

Comment: +1 I'd forgotten about this one. I was really skeptical about it when I first heard of it, but I've tried it myself before now & it does seem to work.

Comment: Does not seem to have any effect on the issue

Comment: It works for me (iPhone 5s, iOS 9.3.5)! This is so weird.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all the other solutions, this one worked: I chose airplane mode, tried to open the app store, got the error message, ignored it, shut down app store, opened app store, had the no connection message, turned off airplane mode and within 30 seconds got icons and search facility back.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that kind of works is resetting but you don't have all the pages available. (featured doesn't load).

Answer (score 0):

Have someone send you a link to an app in the appstore via SMS and then click on the link. It worked for me